# dokku internal connection between apps via docker network

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, networking, dokku

i have multiple apps on dukku ( Nodejs-Express )
lets say :

```
app1.example.com
app2.example.com
app3.example.com
```

my `app1.example.com` connecting to the other apps via `HttpRequest`.

im logging the speed of connecting and stuff and seems like they are connecting through the internet and not the internal docker network. the speed is more like `900ms` or so , so thats not internal speed.

is there a way for me to connect these applications through the **docker network** ?

im thinking using the `/etc/hosts` , but i guess that's not much dynamic and its more like static way of doing this . and im not quite sure if that's possible with files.

PS : im managing the addresses with dokku configs . setting `environment_variables` for `app1.example.com` and set the addressess and get and use them into the `axios` requests.

Comment: Maybe use dokku network commands to add the apps to the same network? https://dokku.com/docs/networking/network/

Comment: This answer contains the commands you can use to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76896027/4546980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by doing this :

- creating a network
- attaching the network to all the applications
- and applications connect through the container name

for example

app1.web1 
app2.web1 
app3.web1