# Linking two not exposed dokku apps

Tags: dokku

I have two apps deployed to the same dokku instance, an `api` service that pulls data from an external api, and an `emailer` service that hits endpoints on the `api` service and sends out emails depending on endpoint data. How can I link the `emailer` app to use the `api` app possibly using something like an env var `API_URL` in the `emailer` app?

The problem is that neither of the services need to be exposed to the web, so I don't want to expose the `api` service (it only needs to be used by the `emailer` service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [attach both apps to a network](https://dokku.com/docs/networking/network/#attaching-an-app-to-a-network) to enable inter-app routing, setting the API_URL env var to the correct value based on the name of the app/process type/port combination you are routing to, and then disabling public app proxying. Below is an example of how to perform this task.

```bash
# create a service named internal-network
dokku network:create internal-network

# attach the apps to the internal-network network
# if one app needs to be able to immediately talk to another on boot
# use the `attach-post-create` property instead of `attach-post-deploy`
dokku network:set api attach-post-deploy internal-network
dokku network:set emailer attach-post-deploy internal-network

# set the environment variable to talk to api
# - `api`: the name of the app
# - `web`: the name of the process
# - `5000`: the port the container process is listening to, usually 5000
dokku config:set emailer API_URL=http://api.web:5000

# disable public proxying of the services
dokku proxy:disable api
dokku proxy:disable emailer

# rebuild the apps so the containers are attached to the internal-network network
dokku ps:rebuild api
dokku ps:rebuild emailer
```

Comment: This worked as expected, but one small change I needed is to attach emailer to the network using `attach-post-create` instead: `dokku network:set emailer attach-post-create internal-network`. It might be because I'm doing a check from the emailer service to the api on email service start

Comment: What does `web` in `api.web:5000` refer to?

Comment: `web` is the process type for the service.